# How do you monitor/terminate long-running threads in a java web container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a web application that contains a java bean for executing a potentially long-running job. I'd like to find a way that I can identify when a thread has been executing for a very long time and then potentially kill it if necessary.

My application runs in Glassfish 3 so I am on Java 1.6. I am just looking for a solution to a potential problem in the future.

EDIT:

To be clear I am looking for something like a tool or utility to monitor a running web application.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Executor Service.

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Runnable(){ ....});//pass your runnable
```

And then you can wait for a specified time:

```
  try {
        int timeOut = 5;
        //Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to
        // complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.
         future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("TimedOut!");
    }

    executor.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: I am actually using an ExecutorService but I have thought of something that might be an issue with it. My ExecutorService is contained in a SessionScoped CDI bean. Could there be an issue with the passivation/serialization of this bean while a task is running?